# MatLab вывод функции

Tags: matlab

Запрограммируйте функцию, которая возвращает sin^2(x)cos(x) из каждого элемента x входной переменной и, таким образом, работает точно так же, как стандартная функция Matlab (то есть «элемент за элементом»). Не используйте циклы for или while для программирования функции.

этот код в функции (имя файла sincos )

```
function [ y ] = sincos( x )
y = power(sin(x),2).*cos(x);
end
```

это вызов функции (имя файла CV2)

```
function_sincos
```

не понимаю почему не вызываеться функция можете помочь

Comment: функция не вызывается, потому что это - ``function_sincos`` - не вызов функции

Answer (score 0):

Функция должна вызываться следующим образом:

```
sincos(x)
```

x в скобках - это заданный аргумент в виде числа или массива чисел.